# Send file as attachment not contents of file

Tags: email, attachment

I'm trying to send a csv file as an attachment through the command line in Ubuntu. Currently, when running what seems to be the right command an e-mail is sent however, the contents of the CSV file are sent in the body instead of an actual file.

Any ideas?
The command used is:

```
mailx -a ./filename email@address.co.uk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command `mutt` for this purpose

`mutt -s "Test mail" -a  /tmp/file.tar.gz -- you@domain.com < /tmp/mailmessage.txt`

Where `/tmp/file.tar.gz` is the attachment and `/tmp/mailmessage.txt` is the content of mail

Comment: I get an error saying unable to attach file.

Comment: Can't stat SOMEONE@SOMETHING.CO.UK: No such file or directory
SOMEONE@SOMETHING.CO.UK: unable to attach file.

Comment: @fiverivers Sorry, I missed '--' in the command. Updated my answer. please check it

Comment: Hey dude,Thanks for your help however, after using that command I am moved to an interactive UI which asks me to specify things like the body/subject etc etc and then I have to manually press y to send the file. Is there anyway to send an attached csv file via email with one command, completely autonomously. Thanks

Comment: @fiverivers yes provide the missing things to the command line (mutt will prompt for missing parts).

Comment: @fiverivers can you copy/paste the command you tried? The above command works for me.Yes, completely autonomously

Answer (score 1):

the code I used

```
mail --subject="what ever" --attach=foo.csv me@me.com <<foobarbaz

mail with file

foobarbaz
```

with

- `--attach` specifying the file to be send
- `<<foobarbaz` is syntax for an here document (i.e. will send to mail all data up to a line begining with foobarbaz )

Edit:

from `man mailx`

- -a, --append=HEADER: VALUE append given header to the message being sent
- -A, --attach=FILE, attach FILE