# How to send an email attachment from terminal?

Tags: command-line, email, mutt

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I think the mutt command is not available with this version of Ubuntu. Then how can I mail an attachment using terminal commands?

Comment: [It is available.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=mutt&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mutt` command may not be installed by default. You can install it using `sudo apt-get install mutt`

Comment: Thank you. Do you know any default mailer commands to send attachments which comes as default? What about sendmail?

Comment: This is a similiar thread. http://askubuntu.com/questions/525559/send-file-as-attachment-not-contents-of-file/525561#525561.

check the 2nd answer.